# How to create an SMTP mail?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I tried to send mail from my asp.net web application.

I want to send my application password to the user mail id, for that I took the password from datatabase using `getdetailss` function.
`btn4getPwd` is the button calling the mailing function.
`txtusername.Text` is the text box containing sending mail address. All values are receiving correctly, no error occur but it's not working ..!

```
protected void btn4getPwd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtusername.Text.Trim() != "")
    {
        em.username = txtusername.Text.Trim();
        DataTable forget = em.getdetailss(10);
        string passwd = (forget.Rows[0]["PassCode"].ToString());


        try
        {
            string Subject = "Your NLS Password";
            string Body = passwd;
            string ToEmail = txtusername.Text.Trim();
            string SMTPUser = "mymail@gmail.com", SMTPPassword = "pswd";

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress(SMTPUser, "AspnetO");
            mail.To.Add(ToEmail);
            mail.Body = Body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 25; 
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SMTPUser, SMTPPassword);
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);
            Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Mail send...!! ')</script>");
        }

        catch (SmtpException ex)
        {
            lbl4get.Text = "SmtpException ";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lbl4get.Text = "Exception";
        }
    }
    else { Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Invalid USERNAME...!! ')</script>"); }

}
```

Comment: Did you try a different port? like 587..?

Comment: Gmail SSL port is 587. Also, Gmail has security measure that blocks custom-made email clients; you have to switch off the security measure.

Comment: Worst "error handling" ever.

Comment: yes I tried port 587 !! still the same response, if the security is the problem then the error will occur on smtp.Send(mail) command  execution  right ??

Comment: @UweKeim am just beginner seeking for help !

Comment: Get rid of all catch phrases to see the _actual_ errors that occur.

Comment: @Tommy No. You just need the right combination of credentials, port and sender address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`smtp.Port = 25;` is default port but for as you are sending over `SSL` use port `587` or `465` (nonstandard, but sometimes used for legacy reasons). Assume `NetworkCredential` are correct.